# How get second array key if both array value match?

Tags: php, arrays

I try to get second array key to print like first array.
My store_name array having value like : `['Tiffin Sada 7x2.jpg', 'TCMK001P.jpg'];` and my file_name array having value like : `['TCMK001P.jpg', 'Tiffin Sada 7x2.jpg'];`

Below i given my php code what i try:

```
$store_name = $_POST['file_name'];  //$_POST
$file_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"]; //$_FILES

foreach ($store_name as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $file_name)){
        echo $_FILES["image"]["name"][$key];
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

and get output like

TCMK001P.jpg
Tiffin Sada 7x2.jpg

So how can i get **$file_name key** to get out put like:

Tiffin Sada 7x2.jpg
TCMK001P.jpg

Comment: Iterate over `$file_name` then.

Comment: are you want to array element in reverse order ?

Comment: Have you tried my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can iterate in $file_name array and look in $store_name array 
   $store_name  = ['Tiffin Sada 7x2.jpg', 'TCMK001P.jpg'];
    $file_name  = ['TCMK001P.jpg', 'Tiffin Sada 7x2.jpg'];
    $new_rray = array();
    foreach ($file_name as $key => $value) {
      if(in_array($value, $store_name)){
        $new_rray[] = $store_name[$key];
     }
    }
    print_r($new_rray);
```

Comment: but i want order like $store_name array

Comment: can you put exact output you want ?

Comment: have look at it now Array ( [0] => Tiffin Sada 7x2.jpg [1] => TCMK001P.jpg ) this is what I get as output

Comment: Have you got the solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your element by using `array_push` and `array_reverse`

```
$store_name = $_POST['file_name'];  //$_POST
$file_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"]; //$_FILES
$rev=array();    
foreach ($store_name as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $file_name)){       
        array_push($rev,$_FILES["image"]["name"][$key]);
    }
}

print_r(array_reverse($rev));
```

Comment: `array_push()` works as `[]`, but `array_push` is [slower](https://3v4l.org/rZJBT)